# Another way to write a query to count values in one row without a long list

Tags: sql, count

Is there a way to write out a query using `COUNT()` to calculate numeric values without having to list 50+ columns?

Example:

| PartNumber | BOX1 | BOX2 | Box3 | Box4 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NF342-2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | Null |  |
| JKW23-34 | Null | 1 | 2 | Null |  |
| 234-23F | 4 | Null | Null | Null |  |

I want the outcome to be this:

| PartNumber | BOX1 | BOX2 | Box3 | Box4 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NF342-2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | Null | 4 |
| JKW23-34 | Null | 1 | 2 | Null | 3 |
| 234-23F | 4 | Null | Null | Null | 4 |

Thanks

Comment: That's a fairly basic design flaw.  `BoxN` means each box is not dependent only on the primary key.  If you address that issue, counting/summing becomes much more convenient down one column, not across N columns.  Having said that, information_schema can be used to construct that kind of query, without manually writing the SQL, assuming those column names are identifiable.

Comment: @JonArmstrong When using information_schema is there a reason why Column_Default is Null and Numeric_Precision is null? I have values in some columns but it is showing null in all columns.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEmcB.png          https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngtJW.png

Comment: Not all data types have a numeric precision. And not all columns have a default value.

Comment: BTW, you want `+`, not count().

Comment: @jarlh If I do that, wouldn't that just add the values rather then counting if each row has a value?   https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKiF6.png

Comment: Show us your current query (simplified, box1 to biox4.)

Comment: @jarlh This is what I would write if I was to do this with what I know. But it doesn't give me the value I want.      https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmv1F.png

Comment: It looks like you are confused about count and your data model - your data is not normalised, your columns should be rows, it's that simple; fix your data or you're continually flogging a dead horse.

Comment: @Stu Ok, when switching the positions I will use Pivot to convert my columns into rows, and my rows into columns. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON to solve this problem. So JSON has an object value type. We will be filter only number type objects (columns).
Example:

```
select s1.*, s2.total from examples.table1 s1 
inner join 
    (
            select main.partnumber, sum((main.pval::text)::integer) as total from (
                select a1.partnumber, json_typeof(t1.pval) as ptype, t1.pkey, t1.pval from (
                    select aa.partnumber, json_strip_nulls(row_to_json(aa)) as pdata from examples.table1 aa
                ) a1 
                inner join json_each(a1.pdata) t1(pkey, pval) on true 
            ) main 
            where main.ptype = 'number'
            group by main.partnumber
    ) s2 on s1.partnumber = s2.partnumber
```

Result this select:

| partnumber | box1 | box2 | box3 | box4 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NF342-2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |  | 4 |
| JKW23-34 |  | 1 | 2 |  | 3 |
| 234-23F | 4 |  |  |  | 4 |